# TypeError: object PublicChatConsumer can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

I am using python ,django and creating a chat web with django channels
i'm getting this error :

> File
> "C:\Users\guest1.virtualenvs\chatkaro-rdA4zw_Z\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py",
> line 116, in **call**
> return await application( TypeError: object PublicChatConsumer can't be used in 'await' expression WebSocket DISCONNECT
> /public_chat/2/ [127.0.0.1:51079]

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
import json
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class PublicChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        """
        Called when the websocket is handshaking as part of initial connection.
        """
        print("PublicChatConsumer: connect: " + str(self.scope["user"]))
        
        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, code):
        """
        Called when the WebSocket closes for any reason.
        """
        
        print("PublicChatConsumer: disconnect")
        pass
    

    async def receive_json(self, content):
        
        command = content.get("command", None)
        print("PublicChatConsumer: receive_json: " + str(command))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `as_asgi()` after the `Consumer` object in your url patterns

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/', Consumer.as_asgi()),
]
```